# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google' in GCP app

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Django app that I am trying to deploy to GCP. The app works perfectly fine when I run it locally, and it deploys with no issue to GCP (via gcloud app deploy). When I open the webpage, I get this error "502 Bad Gateway 502 nginx" due to "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'". I haven't been able to find how to properly import google into my GCP app. More details below, any help is appreciated.

Here is the parsed stack trace (via GCP debugger):

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
at <module> (/srv/socha_web/settings.py:14)
at _call_with_frames_removed (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219)
at exec_module (<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:728)
at _load_unlocked (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:677)
at _find_and_load_unlocked (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:967)
at _find_and_load (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:983)
at _gcd_import (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1006)
at import_module (/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py:127)
at __init__ (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:142)
at _setup (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:63)
at __getattr__ (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:76)
at setup (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py:19)
at _call_with_frames_removed (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219)
at exec_module (<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:728)
at _load_unlocked (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:677)
at _find_and_load_unlocked (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:967)
at _find_and_load (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:983)
at _gcd_import (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1006)
at import_module (/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py:127)
at import_app (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py:358)
at load_wsgiapp (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py:39)
at load (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py:49)
at wsgi (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py:67)
at load_wsgi (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py:144)
at init_process (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py:119)
at spawn_worker (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:583)
```

And here is my settings.py file (I wiped any secret keys):

```
import os
from google.oauth2 import service_account
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'secret_key'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
# IF TESTING LOCALLY, SWITCH THIS TO True
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', "https://app-number.wl.r.appspot.com",]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True


# SOCIAL AUTH CONFIG START
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'socha_web.pipeline.profile.create_profile'
)
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]


LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'search'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'

SOCIAL_AUTH_POSTGRES_JSONFIELD = True


# eventually need to change this to environment variables
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = 'fb_auth_key'        # App ID
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'fb_secret' # App Secret
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['user_friends', 'email'] # add this
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {       # add this
  'fields': 'id, name, email, picture.type(large), link, friends'
}
SOCIAL_AUTH_USERNAME_IS_FULL_EMAIL = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_EXTRA_DATA = [                 # add this
    ('name', 'name'),
    ('email', 'email'),
    ('picture', 'picture'),
    ('link', 'profile_url'),
    ('friends', 'friends')
]
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_API_VERSION = '7.0'


# SOCIAL AUTH CONFIG END



# GAE SETTINGS.py does the following "ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'social_django',
    'frontend_login',
    'frontend_profile',
    'frontend_writing',
    'frontend_wall',
    'frontend_feed',
    'frontend_footer',
    'master_style_js',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'socha_web.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends', # add this
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect', # add this
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

# [START db_setup]
if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
    # Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
    # the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    # root user(postgres)
    # root password
    # can add users in cloud console, just leaving as root for now
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/app-number:us-west1:app-instance',
            'USER': 'user',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
            'NAME': 'name',
        }
    }
else:    
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '5432',
            'NAME': 'app',
            'USER': 'user',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
        }
    }

# [END db_setup]

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# [START staticurl]
# Fill in your cloud bucket and switch which one of the following 2 lines
# is commented to serve static content from GCS
# STATIC_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/<your-gcs-bucket>/static/'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'upload_bucket'
GS_PROJECT_ID = "app-number"
GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    "socha_web/app-key.json"
)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I haven't been able to find how to properly import google into my GCP app, any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependencies for Python applications can be declared in a standard `requirements.txt` file.
Create a `requirements.txt` at the root of your source code directory, to enumerate all the module dependencies your application requires(the google module is the only one needed in this example):

```
google-api-python-client
```

When you deploy to App Engine, the dependencies specified in the `requirements.txt` file will be installed automatically with your deployed app. You can use any Linux-compatible Python package, including packages that require native C extensions.

Comment: The same error is there even when I add it to requirements.txt. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I just reproduced and realized that the correct module name is not `google`. I've updated my answer. You must add `google-api-python-client` in `requirements.txt`